# Passing mulltiple className as a props

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I have modular component using css module as styling method, let's say `component.js` and `component.module.scss`.  what I want to achieve is to use the component with className as prop.

```js
// component.js

import React from 'react';
import Style from './grid.module.scss';

const Grid = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className={`${Style[props.test]}`}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Grid;
```

```
// component.module.scss

.foo {
  // some style here...
}

.bar {
  // some style here...
}
```

The problem is that `Style[props.test]` doesn't work if the props has more than one class name.

For example

```js
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import Grid from './component';

// Working
<Grid test="a">Baz</Grid> // the output is class="a--3ofml"

// doesnt work
<Grid test="a b">Baz</Grid>  // the output is class="undefined"
```

How to have code that working with multiple props value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can do something like this:

```
return (
   <div className={
      props.test.split(' ').map(s => `${Style[s]}`).join(' ')
    }>
      {props.children}
   </div>
)
```

[Used this as a reference.](https://github.com/rtsao/csjs/wiki/How-to-apply-multiple-classnames-to-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
const Grid = (props) => {
    let cls = props.test.split(" ");
    let styleNames = "";
    cls.forEach(el => {
        styleNames = styleNames + Style[el] + " ";
    })
    return (
        <div className={styleNames}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```